# Как убрать задержку на нажатие кнопки в тг боте?

Tags: python, aiogram

Доброй ночи, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне можно убрать задержку на нажатие инлайн кнопки.

Суть в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку назад удалялось последние сообщение от бота, но если мы сразу же попробуем нажать на инлайн кнопку (она подсвечивается белым цветом после нажатия), то ничего не произойдёт, пользователю придётся подождать некоторое время и после он сможет заново нажать на инлайн кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задержка зависит напрямую от того, какие каллбэки с неё срабатывают, но можно схитрить, если асинхронно сначала изменить сообщение и убрать кнопки, потом дождаться отработки функций и затем высветить результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ожидание обработки callback. Чтобы его погасить сделай callback.answer()